# Does Kodi Require a GUI?

Tags: server, kodi

I'm interested in setting up a Kodi server on my install of ubuntu server on my server in the basement.

It doesn't have a gui. Is this a pre-requisite to use kodi?

I get this error on startup:

```
sarah@scilab_comp_0:~$ kodi --standalone
ERROR: Unable to create GUI. Exiting
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
Crash report available at /home/sarah/kodi_crashlog-20190519_062518.log
```

Comment: What do you mean by Kodi server? Kodi ***is*** a GUI. Kodi can use a SQL server and a file server for various tasks, but those are not a part of kodi, merely used by kodi.

Comment: @vidarlo Perhaps I have the wrong idea. I thought that kodi is a personal media server application meant to distribute media to other devices. Wouldn't this be best run on a server?

Comment: It can distribute media to other devices, but *primarily* it's a GUI. There's other media servers that's better if your only goal is to distribute media.

Comment: In addition, [the manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/kodi.1.html) explains `--standalone`. In short it makes kodi not expect a window manager and somewhat modifies behaviour.

Comment: @vidarlo Would you personally have any recommendations? I've been having trouble with gerbera, not sure what's up with it.

Comment: I use LibreELEC, a dedicated OS for Kodi that works on a Raspberry Pi, I either play media from an attached drive or from the wireless home network.

Comment: Emby server is very easy to use and does what you want much better than Kodi (and the server doesn't require a GUI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kodi is a GUI media player
No out-of-the-box Headless Kodi exists
BUT some users have worked on an [headless Docker image of Kodi](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-kodi-headless/tree/Leia)
Another one have worked on a fake Xorg display with [XRPA](https://www.xpra.org/)

You can find all information about those on the [Kodi Forum](https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=212061&page=31&highlight=headless)

[image: KodiLogo]